# Set up team city 7.1.5 agent checkout and vpn

Tags: git, teamcity, vpn, teamcity-7.0, teamcity-7.1

I am trying to set up team city with git. I have team city **server on 1** machine a and team city **agent on 2**. Also we have vpn enabled on the **agent** machine, that allows get access to stash server. I am using default private key method for authorization. And I get error like this:

Test connection failed in ---. List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException:---.

Question: Do I need to set up vpn on the teamcity server or it is needed only on teamcity agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for TC 7.x says the following:

> Please note that this mode affects only sources checkout. Current
>   revision and changes data retrieving logic is executed by the TeamCity
>   server and thus TeamCity server should have access to VCS server in
>   any mode.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Mode

If the only way to access you source code repositories in stash are via the VPN you'll need to set up the VPN on the TeamCity server as well - even if the checkout mode is set to "Automatically on agent".